# Deriving the tax incidence formula -- what am I doing wrong?

Tags: taxation, elasticity

I'm trying to derive the tax incidence for an excise $t$ so that producers receive $p$ and consumers pay $q=p+t$ per unit. The formula I am seeing everywhere is some version of

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}p}{\mathrm{d}t}
=
\frac{\epsilon_D}{\epsilon_S - \epsilon_D},
$$

but I keep ending up (derivation below) with:

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}p}{\mathrm{d}t}
=
\frac{\epsilon_D}{(q/p) \epsilon_S - \epsilon_D}.
$$

I use definitions of elasticity
$\epsilon_D = \frac{q}{D}\frac{\partial D}{\partial q}$
and
$\epsilon_S = \frac{p}{S}\frac{\partial S}{\partial p}$.
I can see that I would get the expected result if I used $\epsilon_D = \frac{p}{D}\frac{\partial D}{\partial q}$ instead, but surely this would not be sound, since the consumer adjusts their demand based on $q$, not $p$?

What is my mistake here?

### My derivation

Starting from the equilibrium condition

$$ D(q) = S(p), $$

I differentiate by $t$ to get

$$
\frac{\partial D}{\partial q}
\frac{\mathrm{d} q}{\mathrm{d} t}
+
\frac{\partial D}{\partial q}
\frac{\partial q}{\partial p}
\frac{\mathrm{d} p}{\mathrm{d} t}
=
\frac{\partial S}{\partial p}
\frac{\mathrm{d} p}{\mathrm{d} t},
$$

Which rearranges to

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} p}{\mathrm{d} t}
=
\frac{
\frac{\partial D}{\partial q}
}{
\frac{\partial S}{\partial p}
-
\frac{\partial D}{\partial q}
},
$$

Noting that $\frac{\partial q}{\partial p} = \frac{\partial q}{\partial t} = 1$.

Now I apply the definitions of the elasticities $\epsilon_D = \frac{q}{D}\frac{\partial D}{\partial q}$ and $\epsilon_S = \frac{p}{S}\frac{\partial S}{\partial p}$, giving

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} p}{\mathrm{d} t}
=
\frac{
\frac{D}{q}\epsilon_D
}{
\frac{S}{p} \epsilon_S
-
\frac{D}{q} \epsilon_D
}
=
\frac{\epsilon_D}{\frac{q}{p} \epsilon_S - \epsilon_D},
$$

where I simplify by dividing through with $\frac{D}{q}$ (recalling that $S = D$).

Comment: Looking at these [slides](https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/stantcheva/files/lecture3.pdf) it seems that the tax incidence is the derivative of price with respect to tax evaluated for a tax $t = 0$. In this case $q = p$ so the ratio becomes 1.